# How to reinstall purchased software after OS reinstallation?

Tags: software-center, games, paid-applications

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Downloading a previously purchased app with Ubuntu Software Center](https://askubuntu.com/questions/240626/downloading-a-previously-purchased-app-with-ubuntu-software-center)

A month or so ago I purchased Bastion on the Ubuntu software center. I noticed it was running really slowly, so I tried to get the driver for my Graphics Card. In doing so I completely messed up the resolution on my screen, and couldn't get it back. I backed up my files using the stock Ubuntu software and did a fresh install, and restored my files. Unfortunately Bastion was not restored.

Is there any way I can get it back, or will I have to buy it again?