# Downloading a previously purchased app with Ubuntu Software Center

Tags: software-center, minecraft

Fresh install of Ubuntu 12.10 but I want to claim a purchase of Minecraft that I bought with the old install using Ubuntu Software Center. Don't see an intuitive way of downloading your purchased items. I have the email payment confirmation. Any advice?

Answer (score 4):

- With the Ubuntu Software Center open go to ***File*** > ***Reinstall Previous Purchases***

[image]

- Login with the account you used to purchase the software

[image]

- After you have done that a list of available purchased software will be displayed. Select the software you previously bought and press install

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using the Ubuntu Software Center simply go to File --> Reinstall Previous Purchases to reinstall software you've already purchased.