# Will U1 phase out affect apps purchased in the Software Center?

Tags: software-center, ubuntu-one

I've just found the way to reinstall Humble Bundle games after I migrate to the latest LTS. I just need to confirm that this method is still valid even after U1 is gone.

The method to reinstall is described in this thread: [Downloading a previously purchased app with Ubuntu Software Center](https://askubuntu.com/questions/240626/downloading-a-previously-purchased-app-with-ubuntu-software-center)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was given to me on the [ubuntu launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-center/+bug/1311027). Installing ubuntu-sso-client-qt solves the issue

Answer (score 0):

It's Ubuntu One Files what it's being closed, not the whole Ubuntu One accounts so it shouldn't affect you.

Comment: Tried and got burned: after starting the software center from the console, I can see it tries to connect to U1, and fails. Might be because it does not have my credentials saved anywhere, but I don't know where to put them.

Answer (score 0):

No, the Software Center should not be affected by the closing of Ubuntu One file sync related services. If there are any issues that do come up with Software Center as a result, it is a bug that should be reported.

Comment: It seems the phase out of U1 did have an impact in the end. I found someone else impacted and commented. Shame dev couldn't see this coming. [link](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-center/+bug/1311027)